# Updating jQuery Item during Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an ajax call to send out a couple of emails when the user clicks a button.  I am trying to update a "Please wait..." div before and after the call with the status, as well as report any errors.  The problem... is that the div doesn't actually update until the ajax call is complete.

If I comment out the ajax call the status update works fine, but fails if the ajax call takes place.  My Windows programming experience tells me the div needs to be refreshed, but I'm not sure how this is done, or if this is the right method.

For example:

```
$("#msgEmail").show();
$("#msgEmail").html("Preparing to send");
$.ajax({ blah blah blah...
```

Any pointers in the right direction will be much appreciated!

**On nnnnnn's suggestion I started testing on other browsers.  The problem occurs on Chrome and Safari, but works as expected on Firefox and SeaMonkey.  It sure looks like he's right about this.   Now I just need to figure out to implement setTimeout() in this scenario.**

Update: Code:
        .click(function() { 
            $('#myTable :checkbox:checked').each(function() {

```
            sId = $(this).attr('cid');
            sName = $(this).attr('cname');

            ret = true;
            $("#msgImage").slideDown();

            sUpdate = 'Sending alerts to class: '+ sName;
            $("#msgEmail").slideDown();
            $("#msgEmail").html(sUpdate);

            sSubject = "Notificatiom";
            sMessage = $('#message').val();
            sData= "cid="+sId+'&sname='+sName+'&subject='+sSubject+'&message='+encodeURIComponent(sMessage);
            $.ajax({
              url: 'dostuff.php',
              data: sData,
              dataType: 'text',
              type: 'POST',
              async: false,
                success: function (msg) 
                {
                  if(msg >= '1')    
                  { 
                    ret = true;
                  }
                }
            });

        if(ret)
            $("#msgEmail").html('Finished sending alerts');


        $("#msgImage").slideUp();
        ret = false;
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Please show all your code.  The `<div>` doesn't need to be refreshed, as that is what the `.html()` method accomplishes.

Comment: Please don't tell me you're doing SJAX.

Comment: I've found behaviour on this sort of thing varies between browsers, specifically something similar to your code worked fine for me in FF but not IE7. To get it to work in IE I think I ended up triggering the `$.ajax()` call via a `setTimeout()` with a delay of 1ms - seemed to give the browser the chance to repaint the screen and show the status message. (@Slaks - in my case it was definitely an async call but still IE didn't want to refresh.)

Comment: Code is missing curly brace, please fix (hard to see where you intended the for-each loop to terminate).

Answer (score 0):

Place your ajax call in the callback for 'slideDown'.  Set the message before calling 'slideDown'.  This will ensure your message is updated before the ajax call is sent.'

```
sUpdate = 'Sending alerts to class: ' + sName;

$("#msgEmail").html(sUpdate);
$("#msgEmail").slideDown(function() {
    sSubject = "Notificatiom";
    sMessage = $('#message').val();
    sData = "cid=" + sId + '&sname=' + sName + '&subject=' + sSubject + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(sMessage);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dostuff.php',
        data: sData,
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg >= '1') {
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Similar to my original code, placing the ajax call in the slideDown function works properly on Seamonkey and FF, but not Chrome, Safari, or IE.

Comment: It will work if you set the sUpdate before the slideDown as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I ll get you an on hw this stuff is going to be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url :'YOur url',
    .....
   .....

    ajaxSend :function(){
    $('#yourdiv').html('please wait...');
   }
   success:function(msg){
      if (msg >= '1') {
       $('#yourdiv').html('validated');
      }

   }
});

}):
```